# About trimmed inner product

Tags: statistics, inner-products, regression, robust-statistics

Recently, I have read a paper titled as "[Robust Sparse Regression under Adversarial Corruption](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~cmcaram/pubs/ChenCaramanisMannor.RobustRegression.pdf)" appeared in ICML 2013, which is one of the most famous and top conference in machine learning（actually, many papers are talking about applied mathematics）.

This paper proposed a method to solve sparse regression problem in a robust scenario when there exists some corruptions in $X$. The mean idea is very simple, i.e., replacing the ordinary inner product as **trimmed inner product**, and the definition is trimmed inner product $\left< a,b\right>_{n_1}$ described as [algorithm to compute trimmed inner product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYczE.jpg).

---

1. **Input**: $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $n_1$,
2. Compute $q_i = a_ib_i, i = 1,...,N.$
3. Sort $\{|q_i|\}$ and select the smallest $(N − n_1)$ ones. Let $\Omega$ be the set of selected indices.
4. **Output**: $h =  \sum_{i\in\Omega} q_i$.

---

So my question is:

> Is the definition of **trimmed inner product** new, are there some similar ideas in statistics or some other fields? Why is this more robust when facing corruptions? Could any one provide some intuitions?

Comment: Trimmed mean is pretty well known. Notice that the trimmed inner product isn't really an inner product.